# PHP page, refresh and load other page every other time

Tags: php

I'd like to achieve the following. A PHP page refreshes every 20 s and every other time either page1.php should be included or page2.php. Is there an easy way to do it?

First time the page refreshes: Include page2.php, next time the page refreshes: Include page1.php, then again page2.php etc.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
header("Refresh: 20;");

include('page1.php');

?>
```

Edit: I came up with this solution. Is that optimal?

```
<?php
session_start();

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
header("Refresh: 20;");

if(!isset($_SESSION['page'])){
    include('page1.php');
    $_SESSION['page'] = "1";
} else {
    unset ($_SESSION["page"]);
    include('page2.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: The easiest way is probably to create a counter in `$_SESSION`

Comment: Because the page refresh, I think you need a database to store the previous value of 'include' so you can choose which print on every refresh based on the value saved on the database

Comment: store it on session instead

Comment: Additional question: Will the session be destroyed automatically? Because session_start() is called after every refresh.

Comment: @smolo no, by the nature of sessions they will not be destroyed between loads

Comment: unset session variables is awkward. It would be better to actually set the session as a certain value; ie; value "yes"/ or "no" or as defined in Jerson's answer.

Comment: I'm not unseting the session, but the session variable.

Comment: How to destroy the sessions automatically?

Comment: `$_SESSION = [];` is the best way

Comment: Where's the best place to add $_SESSION = []; ?

Comment: updated my answer, using boolean is great than emptying the session

Comment: You can add the `$_SESSION = [];` to replace the unset session command. But be aware this will empty the entire session data.

Comment: Therefore it's probably not a good idea to set $_SESSION = []; since this will empty the session data as well and the page changing wouldn't work anymore. The question remains if calling session_start(); repeatedly without destroying the session is going to cause any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session like this

```
session_start();

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
header("Refresh: 20;");

if(!isset($_SESSION['page']) || !$_SESSION['page']) {
    $_SESSION['page'] = true;
    include 'page2.php';
} else {
    $_SESSION['page'] = false;
    include 'page1.php';
}
```

and note: You need separate your session_start() on other php file and include it this php file

Comment: This solution will fail to include a page when first loaded, i.e. when `$_SESSION['page']` is empty

Comment: Thanks, I found a similar solution without having seen yours first. (see my edited post)

Comment: Jerson, I tweaked your IF statement, it was running the same criteria through several shorthand qualfiiers. It is easier on PHP to check if something is *truthy* than if something is *falsey*

Comment: @Martin does this not return with undefined index if first load?, although i test your edited code and give me a warning with , undefined index , better to check using isset